C# Hosting: How do I avoid exception messages from crashed BackgroundServices in STDOUT
We're using structured logging on all our services, so all logs are in json format. When a BackgroundService crashes, it prints a cleartext stacktrace onto STDOUT. I'd like to be able to catch exceptions from BackgroundServices, log them in a structured way and then exit the service. Is there a way to do that without using something like System.Exit()?
I've tried switching from IHostedService to BackgroundService because in that version, the service would just ignore the crashed background task, which is not what I wanted either. I'd like the whole system to crash but not to trash my structured output.

May I understand your concern as: the BackgroundService might crash for some reason and there must be en exception when it's crashed due to an exception, you want your BackgroundService could log the exception information before it's completely crashed? If so, I'm afraid there shall be a background monitor mechanism to monitor the background service so that it could detect the exception and log them, just somewhat like what event viewer did for windows OS and other applications. In the meantime, why not add more try catch struction to where might throw  exception and avoid the crash?

Could you enclose everything in the overridden ExecuteAsync() in a try-catch block that handles this failure?
Maybe StopApplication() could help?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers#:~:text=hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()%3B
How to cancel manually a BackgroundService in ASP.net core

This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.
